# PHP Laravel is not able to connect to cloud sql on google could appengine

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am trying to connect my laravel application to MySQL instance on Cloud SQL. 
I get the error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`

I am following this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible.

I have the following app.yaml

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

env_variables:
  ## Put production environment variables here.
  APP_NAME: MyApp
  APP_ENV: dev
  APP_DEBUG: true
  APP_KEY: base64:AEoXa4s+7hRiWuFnFcR+Xm/he891r1wpM3tGfkH7lqQ=
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  SESSION_DRIVER: database
  CACHE_DRIVER: database
  MAPS_GOOGLE_KEY: <SOME_KEY>
  ## Database Configurations
  DB_CONNECTION: mysql
  DB_PORT: 3306
  DB_DATABASE: <NAME>
  DB_USERNAME: root
  DB_PASSWORD: <PASSWORD>
  DB_SOCKET: '/cloudsql/<CONNECTION_NAME>'
  LOG_CHANNEL: stackdriver

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: sourcing-279920:<CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:3306

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 7
```

Where Also, I enabled the SQL Admin API.

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "gonoware/laravel-maps": "^1.3",
        "google/cloud-error-reporting": "^0.16.4",
        "google/cloud-logging": "^1.20",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel-frontend-presets/bulma": "^3.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize",
            "chmod -R 755 bootstrap/cache",
            "php artisan config:cache",
            "php artisan migrate",
            "php artisan db:seed"
        ]
    }
}
```

P.S: I am able to connect through the proxy.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First I think that `cloud_sql_instances:` in `beta_settings` should be in quotation marks.

If this is not solve the problem, you can try to check this [Github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/1015) which is linking to [another issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/issues/351#) that seems to contain resolution.

I found something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130208/gcloud-app-deploy-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory) here on SO as well.

I hope it will help to solve it!